# I can't boot my ubuntu because of this apci error (could not resolve symbol)(ae not found)?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, acpi

I am new to this stuff, it was working fine until I restart it and got this error it is a two line like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej82q.jpg

It works when I disable my gpu, but if I enable my gpu it will vuse this error.
I the last thing i install is steam and its requirements it works fine.

My specs are:
Gpu:Nvidia gt710 2gb
Cpu:amd a6
Ram:8gb
Edit: I have amd integrated graphics too and a ddr3 motherboard

Comment: are these the last errors you see? What drivers are you using for your Nvidia card?

Comment: yes its only that 2 lines repeated, geforce 470  video card driver, something like that, the last version of the driver installed in my ubuntu is 470.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run : sudo apt install - - reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Comment: where can I run this?

Comment: Thanks for you for your solution I didn't run that comand but rather i just reinstall it with my usb with ubuntu boot file

Comment: It will also do almost same thing.